# Naming insecurity

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with proper naming. That issue appears when i try to apply to [*first class collection*](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf) to my class and use [sonar](https://sonarcloud.io/) as well:

```
public class Units {

    private final List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<>();

    [...]
}
```

Here's the problem, sonar says:

> A field should not duplicate the name of its containing class -  [java:S1700](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/martinfrank-github/rules?open=java%3AS1700&rule_key=java%3AS1700)

What would be the **proper name** for the internal representation of my list? Is sonar here just picky?

Comment: This question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: would it be helpful if i would provide the whole context? actually this issue raised because i got warnings in my project on my [github-project](https://github.com/martinFrank/simpleciv/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/martinfrank/simpleciv/game/Players.java) - see [sonar](https://sonarcloud.io/project/issues?id=martinFrank_simpleciv&open=AXAJ2oI1-dJ7i5GckLop&resolved=false&types=CODE_SMELL)

Comment: as i ran into that issue for several time i'm not sure how to handle that best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Class Names that are Plural

I don't know if it's a convention, but for example the `java.util` package contains two or more classes like`Arrays` and `Collections` that only provide`static` util methods.

[UML](https://www.cs.uct.ac.za/mit_notes/software/htmls/ch05s09.html) recommends that class names be written in singular.

## Variable Scope

The scope of the `List <Unit> units` field is tied to its class and should be understood in its context.

If you renamed it to `collection` because of the context, it is still clear that it contains all the units. It even has an advantage: If you rename your class from `Units` to `Chunks`, you do not have to touch the variable `collection` because it do not follow the [Type Embedded in Name](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/) code smell any more.

---

I name my Collection-Classes with a `Collection`-suffix: `UnitCollection`. But I know that `Units` sounds and looks cooler :P

But its only a naming problem inside one class - feel free to choose what fits best for you

Comment: i guess naming it `List<Unit> collection` seems like a way to go - that let's open what kind of collection is used (open for change) and prevents naming clash...

Comment: could you come up with a better name for a *first class collection* for my `Units`?

Comment: @MartinFrank i would go with `Units` or `UnitCollection`

Comment: thanks - i **WILL** go with `Units` now and suppress this explicit warning for sonar

Answer (score 1):

Usually naming of a field should follow a simple approach

```
public class Units {

    private final List<Unit> unitList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<Integer,Unit> unitMap = new HashMap<>();

}
```

suffix your field name with the type of collection to ensure better readability.

Comment: I have to disagree with you because it is redundant: `List <Unit> unitList = new ArrayList <> ();` The word `List` appears three times with only 5 words. You also need to rename your variable if you want to change the data type - maybe someone will forget? Variable names should [avoid disinformation](https://cleancoders.com/video-details/clean-code-episode-2)

Comment: i'm not sure if this would not violate *[Avoid Disinformation](https://medium.com/ltunes/what-is-clean-code-naming-conventions-part-1-426d383eb85d)* - sou should not use the type of a variable for it's name (you can't change the type easily afterwards)...

Comment: as mentioned in link to *first class collection*:  **Application of this rule is simple: any class that contains a collection should contain no other
member variables**.

Comment: *hungarian notation* is not a preferred choice in java

Comment: since your answer provides much helpful hints for others i'll +1 it...

Comment: (@MartinFrank should that read *provoked*?)

Comment: @greybeard sometimes being a bad example is helpful for other - as does that question at all seem to be a bad idea... would it be helpful to delete that question?

Comment: (@MartinFrank The question raises an issue I think worth discussing here in a way frowned upon as *hypethetical* (the full text being ***too** hypothetical to be meaningfully reviewed*). The question works for me.)

Comment: @greybeard thanks for appreciating! as mentioned in my comments i do run into that issue again and again and wanted some actual help! there was no interest in an hypothetical question!

Comment: Wow came back to see this awesome comment conversation. This is an eye-opener for me in terms of naming something as simple as a variable.

Comment: thank you again for your answer =) on first glance it seem so easy ^_^ now i'm lost, ahahaha